# Why does this node have itself as a child?

Tags: c++, tree, nodes

I am trying to make a tree of nodes in C++. Essentially, I am starting with a vector of nodes sorted by some weight, and I run through a loop, making a new node with the bottom two of the vector as children, removing those children from the vector, and adding the new parent to the vector, then sorting. It seems to work perfectly fine until it gets to the last part of the loop where it combines the final two nodes into one parent node. One part of my debug tells me that this parent has the correct children, and then the very next debug message says it has itself as a child, and I can't figure out why. Based on results from me setting the children manually, I think for some reason the last two nodes in the vector are one of the children and the new parent node, which shouldn't be possible because I hadn't added it yet. Here is some of the debugging info:

......

NODES:

size = 2

183  78.275
182  55.6462

new node has child 182 and 183 with weight 133.921 and id 184

i am starting a search. my id is 184

i have children. my first child id is 182 and my second is 184

i am starting a search. my id is 182

i have children. my first child id is 178 and my second is 180

......

and then eventually, it predictably works its way down the tree, then back up again to the second child, which is itself for some reason, and it gets stuck in a loop. The first debugging message clearly says which nodes are its children, and the next disagrees. Here is some of the relevant code:

```
while (nodes.size() != 1) { // start combining nodes

        cout << "NODES: " << "\n\n"; // print a list of all the nodes, for me, the human
        int size = nodes.size(); // keep track of the size with an int since we know when it will change and i will be pulling for it a lot
        cout << "size = " << size << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << nodes[i].id << " " << nodes[i].character << " " << nodes[i].weight << endl;
        }

        Node newNode(&nodes[size - 1], &nodes[size - 2], globalID); // create a new node with children as the two nodes at the bottom of the list, which will be the two with the lowest weight because the vector is sorted
        cout << "new node has child " << newNode.child1->id << " and " << newNode.child2->id << " with weight " << newNode.weight << " and id " << newNode.id << endl;
        nodes.pop_back(); // delete the last two nodes in the vector. there is probably a better way to do this, but this works
        nodes.pop_back();
        nodes.push_back(newNode); // add the new parent node to the end of the vector...
        sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), sortNodes); // ...and sort the vector by decreasing weight. i know it would be better to just add the new node to the right spot. i couldnt figure out how, and this works
    }
```

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(); // default constructor
    Node(Node* cld1, Node* cld2, int& globalID); // constructor with children
    Node(char crtr, double wt, int& globalID); // constructor for a character node at the bottom of its branch

    int findDepthOfTree() const; // returns the depth of the tree below and including this node

    void setChild2(Node* chl2);

    double weight; // weight of the node
    string character; // character if the node is the bottom of the branch
    Node* child1; // the two children
    Node* child2;
    int id; // a global id so that i as a human can keep track of them
    bool hasChildren; // true if it is not a character node
};
```

```
Node::Node(Node* cld1, Node* cld2, int& globalID) { // constructor with children
    weight = cld1->weight + cld2->weight; // the weight of the parent is the sum of the childrens weights
    child1 = cld1;
    child2 = cld2;
    id = globalID; // set the id of this node and increment the global counter
    globalID++;
    hasChildren = true;
}
```

If there is anything I'm forgetting let me know.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in a debugger yet?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Node` class stores pointers to the child nodes. When you construct `node`, you store in that object two pointers into the `nodes` vector. A couple of lines later, you call `nodes.pop_back()` twice. This removes the nodes from the vector, and the two pointers you so recently stored in `node` are now *dangling*. Any attempt to dereference them will result in Undefined Behavior.

In your case, since you then follow up those two pops with a `push_back` to add `node` back to the vector, the right child pointer will point at the newly inserted node, and you end up with a node that has itself as a child.

Any `push_back` can move things around if the vector needs to expand its storage, and that `sort` will make a mess of any tree structure you might have.

You will have to rethink how you storing and manipulating the nodes of your tree.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I figured it would be something like that. Is there a better way to have some sort of way to locate a child node from a parent that avoids this, or should I simply not remove the nodes from the vector and not use the sort function? I could add nodes to the vector as I do now without removing the children, marking them inactive, and then manually look through and find the children with the lowest weights each time. I think that would work, and I don't really care about how slow it is, but is there a better way to go about it?